# What is the maximum gym level?

Tags: pokemon-go

What is the maximum gym level and how much prestige does it take to get to this level?

The highest I've seen is 4 and it was 10k/12k prestige, so I assume that there is at least 5.

Answer (score 20):

It's 10. Unless there are different kinds of gyms. Got mine to level 10 and it said 50k/50k prestige

Comment: The prestige can go higher, or at least to 52k when the last pokemon is added.

Answer (score 11):

For the sake of completeness, here a Screenshot which is showing a full-stacked gym with a prestige of `52000/50000`:

[image]

Comment: I've seen a gym with 54000/50000 prestige.

Comment: Yep, there is one a few blocks from here that has a war between the night shift and the morning shift (morning shift usually ends up lasting longer) but, the morning shift will knock down the night shift, add a few people, then pump it up to the max with 7 empty slots, people will add mons on their way to work past it and the prestige will sometimes show 54000/50000