# How is (52000 / 50000) gym prestige possible?

Tags: pokemon-go

I set-up a level 10 gym today. After hitting 50,000, I wanted to bump prestige up a little more but could not. A few hours later the gym was briefly attacked and prestige fell to 47,000. I fought back and raised prestige to 49,000, then left for a few hours.

Someone chipped-in with gym defense and currently, the prestige level is exactly (52,000 / 50,000). How is this possible when I couldn't go above 50,000?

Comment: It's Niantic, so it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because to put the tenth pokemon into the gym a gym needs to have 50k/50k prestige. At this point you can no longer train the gym to increase the prestige level.

However a gym will still gain the 2k prestige bonus from placing pokemon into the gym. This means that the gym will go to 52k total prestige.

Although I've never seen it, it should also imply that placing multiple pokemon into a gym with 50k prestige will increase the prestige by 2k*number of pokemon. Assuming this is true and a gym is trained to 50k prestige with only one defender, you will be able to increase the prestige to 68k prestige (50k + 2k*9).

Comment: Leveling a gym to 10 without placing Pokemon in it sounds incredibly painful.

Comment: confirmed. That is *exactly* what happened. thanks!

Comment: @Ellesedil Very painful. But, I'm so proud be a member of level 9 (someone just attacked) gym that I'll defend to my last unit of stardust.

Comment: Painful if your intention is to cap gyms. if your intention is to keep it as long as you can, you want as many people to help hold it as can fit. You do this by pumping it up to 10 with only your 1 guy in there, then as people see open spots, they just come in and add one, easy peasy lemon squeezey, no need to battle it up on their own, so they will be more likely to stop and add one. If this gym is well known, people will start to add bigger and better ones knowing that YOU are willing to fight to keep it and that the lower CPs will get scraped off the bottom