# Does Pokémon Go recognize gym prestige higher than 52k?

Tags: pokemon-go

I joined a level 10 gym with 60k/50k prestige, which was seemingly a gym fortress. But, in less than 45 minutes, I checked the gym's health and it had been demoted into a level 9 gym with 42k/50k prestige. Was 18k really removed *that* quickly?

This gym was created by putting 5 Pokémon in the gym. Next, prestige was taken to 50k while leaving all the openings unfilled. Finally, the openings were filled (2k added per addition), which created a 60k/50k gym.

Now, maybe 60k is just being displayed, but not stored as actual gym health. Does that mean that 52k is the max prestige? Or could a gang of attackers really inflict that much damage so quickly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**, the prestige was never actually at 60k, despite being displayed that way. Prestige never actually is higher than 50k, regardless of how it appears. See [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/51t7lx/if_a_gym_is_at_52k_prestige_maxed_out_and_the_gym/):

> The gym is not actually at 52k prestige - this is simply a bug. The gym is actually at 50k prestige, but due to the way the game handles adding a Pokemon (adding +2,000 Prestige each time) when you add the last defender possible to a Level 10 (maxed out) gym, it makes it go from 50,000/50,000 to - artificially - 52,000/50,000. It really is at 50,000 though.
>   So if you were to attack it, according to recent findings (somebody tested this), it should actually drop down from 52,000 to below 48,000, resulting in somebody getting kicked out (it's just that the total Prestige drop displayed to you may not always match up, essentially because of the bug giving you false numbers to begin with).

Comment: It might actually have some defensive value. I bet many attackers would take a pass on attacking such a fearsome looking gym.

Comment: @Jaqaex, I suppose if you have faith in security by obscurity-- that is, you assume that not many people know that the 50k+ prestige is erroneous and holds no value when attacking the gym. In reality, there is no defensive value if the number means nothing. Defeating the bottom Pokemon a single time would remove it from the gym and demote the gym to level 9. Even if a gym had the "maximum" 68k/50k prestige, successfully defeating the first Pokemon would "remove" over 18k prestige.

Comment: I think the fearsomeness of the gym is simply the fact that it has 10 (hopefully strong) Pokemon in it, and it's going to take a ton of time and a ton of potions to clear out.

Comment: @Ellesedil Yeah but I think Jaqaex was specifically talking about the higher-than-50k prestige rather than the occupants of the gym. In all honesty, I didn't know that it legitimately capped at 50k until I answered this question, though, so I'm going to bet that many people don't know yet, either.

Comment: @Ellesedil In my area (almost) all the gyms are level 10, each with Pokemons between 1800 and 3000 CP. The only real turn-over happens on weekends in  gyms near bars where people watch football. I've always wondered if gyms have become this stagnant in other geographies?

Comment: @Jaqaex I took over a gym in August and it's been blue ever since. Location is one factor, but the updates turned a lot of people off and the hardcore fan base has since dwindled. Plus, people with hacked or illegitimate mons and apps have been getting removed/banned. There's just not as many players. I noticed a lot of my long-time gyms getting attacked once he buddy update was released, which I know brought a lot of people back.

Comment: @Jaqaex I think so, in my area at least. There's 2 gyms visible from my house, and they're both currently level 9 and level 10. Weirdly, one of those belong to team Instinct. Any way, I think it's due to the fact that casual players are playing less and less as time goes on. You have to be actively playing in order to stock enough items from Pokestops to keep leveling and take or improve high level gyms.

Comment: @Vemonus I just realized why all 7 gyms near me are always level 10 team Instinct. There is a huge level 38 cheat. He will counter-attack any attacks. Then he drops a 250 CP Diglet (very high CP/HP ratio). We ferociously attack it with low CP Pidgies to quickly add pretige. That lets people do a drive-by and put in high CP Pokemon. When his Diglet dies, he drops a 3000 CP Dragonite. So... the key is the cheat's counter attack. He can squash any attempt to take our gyms, so people don't try anymore. I think that is what is happening.

Comment: @Jaqaex that may be the case for now, but Niantic is banning users with hacked versions of the game left and right.

Comment: @Vemonus Just saw the final cheat he does is have an 2nd account on a different team. He uses it to control when the Diglet is kicked-out so he can immediately jump-in with a Dragonite / Snorlax... pretty bummed-out. Well, I'm not gonna help him with attacking his Diglet anymore! How can Niantic not notice someone who is level 38???