# In Pokemon Go, how can we join a level 10 gym (of the same team)?

Tags: pokemon-go

Sometimes I will see a level 10 gym of my team. In this case, how can I join this gym?

I assume the more I fight in this gym, the higher the prestige the gym can get, but it will never allow me to join it?

Comment: Related: ["What is the maximum gym level?"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273239/what-is-the-maximum-gym-level?rq=1). In short, you can't - unless you coordinate with someone from another team to lower the gym to level 9 (kicking out the bottom Pokemon) and then training it back up.

Answer (score 4):

A level 10 gym is the highest level gym, if there are less than 10 people in you can join it freely, if there are already 10 people in it you are unable to join. Fighting this gym will not raise the level above 10.

Comment: it will raise the prestige though? (to an amount that has no limit)

Comment: @太極者無極而生 While it'll raise the prestige it won't go to an higher level.

Comment: No, actually, it won't raise the prestige. After a fight, the Gym re-checks its prestige and sets itself back to a max of 50k. The only way to exceed that cap is by adding Pokemon to empty slots for an additional 2k prestige each.

Answer (score 0):

You can as a friend who is from another team to battle that gym. When that gym goes below a certain prestige it will automatically drop the member with the lowest CP level. Then you can go ahead and train the gym, raise its prestige and join that gym.

Or you can wait for somebody to attack the gym, drop the prestige level and hopefully give you a chance to train it back up to level 10.